# How to read a .py file and add code to it?

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a list of `.py` files in `python 3.6`. The aim is to replace/add a bit of code without manually going through all the files and editing the code.

```py
import os

py_files = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(location):
    for name in files:
        if '.py' in name:
            py_files.append(os.path.join(path, name))

test_file = py_file[0]
t = open(test_file,'r').read()  # Trying a read only to check whether I can see the text
print(t)

# assuming this starts working.
#I want to see the file and then use a .replace and save the file. 
#I assume saving it back as `.py` might present a challenge
```

The output I get is `''`.

Not sure how to get this done.

Comment: Did you check the name of the file that ends up in `test_file`? Did you check the contents of the corresponding file? Maybe it got blanked somehow. Anyway, why are you trying to edit code this way - what exactly is wrong with the source files?

Comment: If you have so many scripts that making the same change to each is tedious, they are probably similar enough to replace with a single *paremterized* script.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks. That was the error.

Comment: @chepner that seems like a great idea. Looking into it. Possible to get a hypothetical example?

Comment: @Sid take whatever piece of code you're modifying in all the scripts, and put it in its own module that all the other scripts import.  That way whenever you need to modify it, you're only modifying it in one spot.

Comment: @Samwise it is an import statement that needs to be added to all the `.py` files and a line calling the script.

Comment: @Sid For example, scripts that contain nothing but `print("foo")`, `print("bar")`, `print("baz")`, etc, could be replaced by a single script `import sys; print(sys.argv[1])`, to be called as `script "foo"`, `script "bar"`, script "baz"`, etc.